# Normal ordering and time of fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators

Given a field:
$$
\phi(x)=\phi^+(x)+\phi^-(x)
$$
where
$$
\phi^+(x)=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32E}a_ke^{-ikx}
$$
and
$$
\phi^-(x)=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32E}a^\dagger_k e^{ikx}.
$$
The time ordering of $\phi(x)\phi(y)$ for $x^0>y^0$ is
$$
T\phi(x)\phi(y)=\phi^+(x)\phi^+(y)+\phi^+(x)\phi^-(y)+\phi^-(x)\phi^+(y)+\phi^-(x)\phi^-(y)
$$
which is equal to
$$
T\phi(x)\phi(y)=\phi^+(x)\phi^+(y)+\phi^-(x)\phi^+(y)
+\phi^-(y)\phi^+(x)+\phi^-(x)\phi^-(y)
+[\phi^+(x),\phi^-(y)].
$$
The notes I'm reading says that the first few terms (before the commutator) is equal to the normal ordering of $\phi(x)\phi(y)$, i.e.
$$
:\phi(x)\phi(y):=\phi^+(x)\phi^+(y)+\phi^-(x)\phi^+(y)
+\phi^-(y)\phi^+(x)+\phi^-(x)\phi^-(y).
$$
How so? shouldn't it have $\phi^+(x)\phi^-(y)+\phi^+(y)\phi^-(x)$ for the cross terms instead for it to be time ordered since $\phi^-(x)$ has the creation operator?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which notes?

Comment: oh ya it's correct now, it's on pg 77 here: http://www.physics.gla.ac.uk/~dmiller/lectures/RQF_2010-11.pdf

Comment: What you suggest for crossterms (v2) are anti-normal ordered.

Comment: In normal ordering, you put the annihilation operators on the right. The annihilation operators are in $\phi^+$.

Comment: oh my I'm on a bad streak today, lol Well I guess I badly need to reread my notes. Thanks guys!